# How can I make a simple on-screen HTML keyboard that contains only two buttons and one textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Example

[On screen keyboard](https://online.westpac.com.au/esis/Login/SrvPage/?h3&app=wol&referrer=http://www.westpac.com.au/HomepageAlternative/)

But i want to design keyboard using only two buttons that will contain value 0 and 1 
like this and value should come in textbox

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can i do this ?

Comment: It'd probably be done easiest with HTML and some CSS. The javascript would handle the click events for the buttons and place the values in the text box.

Comment: Looks like you already coded and designed it. lol

Comment: yeh i coded with javascript but i thought anyother way of do it so i asked it on stackoverflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sample html:

```
<input type="text" id="theTextField">
<div id="button0">0</div>
<div id="button1">1</div>
```

sample jquery:

```
var $yourTextField = $('#theTextField');

$('#button0').click(
    function(){
        $yourTextField.val($yourTextField.val()+"0")
    }
)

$('#button1').click(
    function(){
        $yourTextField.val($yourTextField.val()+"1")
    }
)
```